# No indentation in ongoing line in Verse environment

Tags: indentation, verse

The verse environment looks good to me for highlighting and referencing a paragraph. However, I don't like that it automatically indents what doesn't fit in an ongoing line. I would like the overall thing to be indented, but no additional indentation for everything following line one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside=on]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\label{HeisenbergVsObserver}
The uncertainty principle, however, states that there is a fundamental limit to how objectively well-defined these two non-commuting observables can be at any given time.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

As an aside: what do I have to do for stackexchange to compile and show the output of the latex document:

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside=on]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
\label{HeisenbergVsObserver}
The uncertainty principle, however, states that there is a fundamental limit to how objectively well-defined these two non-commuting observables can be at any given time.
\end{verse}
\end{document}

Comment: The `epigraph` package may be more appropriate for this sort of inclusion.

Comment: ok. I've added `\setlength\epigraphwidth{.93\textwidth}` and `\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}`, but now it looks fine though I like the typesetting of verse more. Also, epigraph doesn't stretch characters out till the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the definition of the verse environment in the article class:
\newenvironment{verse}
{\let\=@centercr
\list{}{\setlength\itemsep{\z@}%
\setlength\itemindent{-15\p@}%
\setlength\listparindent{\itemindent}%
\setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}%
\addtolength\leftmargin{15\p@}}%
\item[]}
{\endlist}

You can do what you want by changing it this way in your preamble:

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myepigraph}
{\let\=@centercr
\list{}{\setlength\itemsep{\z@}%
\setlength\itemindent{\z@}%
\setlength\listparindent{\itemindent}%
\setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}%
\addtolength\leftmargin{15\p@}}%
\item[]}
{\endlist}

\makeatother